# Spectrum1D does not recognize u.dimensionless_unscaled quantity as a Quantity

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am preparing for some spectral analysis which will involve combining three overlapping spectra. Two of the spectra have "dimensionless" units (one, and albedo, has units of `flux/flux`; the other, a filter response, is in `photons/photons`). I would like to use `specutils` and `astropy` to make this easier and generally avoid reinventing any wheels.

However, I am having difficulty converting my data into a `Spectrum1D`-type object. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import astropy
from astropy import units as u
from specutils import Spectrum1D

dataSpectrumFileName = 'filename.dat' # Declare filename
dataSpectrumRaw = list(np.loadtxt(dataSpectrumFileName).T) # Load file.
#Now dataSpectrumRaw[0] is the wavelength grid and dataSpectrumRaw[1] is the dimensionless spectrum.

# Declare units
dataSpectrumRaw[0] = [ u.Quantity(dataSpectrumRaw[0][i],u.micrometer) for i in             
range(len(dataSpectrumRaw[0])) ]
dataSpectrumRaw[1] = [ u.Quantity(dataSpectrumRaw[1][i],u.dimensionless_unscaled) for i in 
range(len(dataSpectrumRaw[1])) ]

# Convert to Spectrum1D item
dataSpectrum = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis = dataSpectrumRaw[0], flux = dataSpectrumRaw[1])
```

My expectation is that this will load in my data, convert the raw numerical information into two lists of `Quantity`-type objects (the former with units of `u.micrometer` and the latter with units of `u.dimensionless_unscaled`), then produce a `Spectrum1D`-type object named `dataSpectrum` with all the relevant information and associated functionality. Indeed, a check prior to running the final line of my code snippet reveals:

```
>>>dataSpectrumRaw[0][0]
0.2 um
>>>type(dataSpectrumRaw[0][0])
<class 'astropy.units.quantity.Quantity'>
>>>dataSpectrumRaw[1][0]
0.269681
>>>type(dataSpectrumRaw[1][0])
<class 'astropy.units.quantity.Quantity'>
```

However, on compiling the above code entirely I am given an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[REDACTED]/specutilsExperiments.py", line 40, in <module>
    dataSpectrum = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis = dataSpectrumRaw[0], flux = dataSpectrumRaw[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/spectra/spectrum1d.py", line 71, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Flux must be a `Quantity` object.")
ValueError: Flux must be a `Quantity` object.
```

The documentation and error text both seem to indicate that what I am trying to do SHOULD work. I have also tried converting whole arrays into `u.Quantity` objects, which for some reason does not stick (the elements convert back to `np.float64` before I can operate on them further).

I have then two questions: 1) Why does this not work as expected? 2) How can I make it work as expected?

Please answer both questions if possible; without the answer to 1) I will likely run into this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making things more complicated for yourself than necessary.  Try it like this:

```
>>> spectrum_raw = np.loadtxt(filename).T  # no reason to convert to a list
>>> spectral_axis = spectrum_raw[0] * u.micrometer
>>> flux = spectrum_raw[1] * u.dimensionless_unscaled
>>> spectrum = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=spectral_axis, flux=flux)
>>> spectrum
<Spectrum1D(flux=<Quantity [0.79502858, 0.68160812, 0.04951287, 0.86626975, 0.35146137,
           0.13505172, 0.24077603, 0.65288882, 0.24230813, 0.51846452]>, spectral_axis=<Quantity [0.41284773, 0.23807243, 0.14288542, 0.99212095, 0.75582049,
           0.1175328 , 0.66007513, 0.48731926, 0.07727119, 0.02389908] um>)>
```

In brief, you are creating Python `list`s of `Quantity` scalars, where `list` is the standard heterogeneous collection in Python with no specific meaning.  But an Astropy `Quantity` can store either a single scalar value, or an arbitrarily-sized array of values of the same unit.  So that's what you want when you already have an array of values in the same units.  See [Creating Quantity instances](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/quantity.html#creating-quantity-instances).

It seems maybe you tried this at some point:

> I have also tried converting whole arrays into `u.Quantity` objects, which for some reason does not stick.

Without knowing what you did I can't say why it did not "stick", but the above example should work.  Not also that you can convert an `ndarray` to a `Quantity` simply my multiplying the array by the desired unit.  It is basically syntactic sugar equivalent to `Quantity(array, unit)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; this worked for me. On np.array objects, I had tried converting the axes into u.Quantity objects in situ; i.e. `spectrum_raw[0]=spectrum_raw[0] * u.micrometer`. Perhaps doing the conversion in situ was the issue?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "in situ" here because in the example you just gave it would have to depend what type `spectrum_raw` is.  In any case, I wouldn't bother doing it like that.